# RSS Reader in PHP, some quetions

Tags: php, rss

At the beginning sorry for my language but English is not my mother language :)

So, Nowadays I'm doing an RSS reader for my site. But during this I have met some problems.

1) How can I display news chronologically? I mean now I have mixed everything - the newest news can be at the bottom and the oldest can be at the top of the column.

2) How can I set a limit for display news? For example I want to display only 10 items.

3) How can I show source of some news? I mean now I have only title and date but I want to show to the others from what site is that news also.

Thanks in advance! Greetings!

**DISPLAY RSS NEWS:**

`

```
<?php include "feeds.php"; 

$urls_pl = array('http://feeds.feedburner.com/sportowefakty/TtDh','http://www.goal.pl/rss.php');

$urls = array('http://football-italia.net/rss.xml','http://www.fifa.com/rss/index.xml');

try
{
$feeds = new Feed_Amalgamator;
$feeds->addFeeds( $urls );
$feeds->grabRss();
$feeds->amalgamate();
$feeds_pl = new Feed_Amalgamator;
$feeds_pl->addFeeds( $urls_pl );
$feeds_pl->grabRss();
$feeds_pl->amalgamate();
}
catch ( exception $e )
{
die( $e->getMessage() );
}
?> 
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; padding: 5px;">
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" ><img src="http://www.ligamistrzow.com/img/kraje/1.png" height="10px"> POLSKA </a>
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; padding: 5px;">
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" ><img src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/114777_32086_64_explorer_globe_internet_icon.png" height="15px"> ZAGRANICA</a>
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; display: none;padding: 5px;">
<?php foreach ( $feeds_pl->data as $item ) : extract( (array) $item);?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?></a> <font size="1"><?php echo $pubDate ?></font></br>
<?php endforeach; ?></div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; display: none;padding: 5px;">
<?php foreach ( $feeds->data as $item) : extract( (array) $item);?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?></a> <font size="1"><?php echo $pubDate ?></font></br>
<?php endforeach; ?></div>
</div>

<!-- KONIEC -->`
```

---

**FEEDS.PHP FILE**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
        name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'newboxes') {
            if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<?php class Feed_Amalgamator
{
public $urls = array();
public $data = array();

public function addFeeds( array $feeds )
{
    $this->urls = array_merge( $this->urls, array_values($feeds) );
}

public function grabRss()
{
    foreach ( $this->urls as $feed )
    {
        $data = @new SimpleXMLElement( $feed, 0, true );
        if ( !$data )
        throw new Exception( 'Could not load: ' . $feed );
        foreach ( $data->channel->item as $item )
        {
            $this->data[] = $item;
        }
    }
}

public function amalgamate()
{
    shuffle( $this->data );
    $temp = array();
    foreach ( $this->data as $item )
        {
            if ( !in_array($item->link, $this->links($temp)) )
            {
                $temp[] = $item;
            }
    }
    $this->data = $temp;
    shuffle( $this->data );
}

private function links( array $items )
{
    $links = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        $links[] = $item->link;
    }
    return $links;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplepie feed parser is your best friend:

http://simplepie.org/